# copy JSON formatted messages from a kafka topic to another topic in AVRO format

Tags: json, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka-connect setup running where a source connector reads structured records from text files and store into a topic in JSON format (with schema). There is a sink connector running which is inserting those messages into a Cassandra Table. While this setup is running fine, I needed to introduce another sink connector to transfer those messages to HDFS also. So I tried to implement the HDFSSinkConnector (CP 3.0). But this connector expects that the messages would be AVRO formatted and hence throwing errors like 'Failed to deserialize data to Avro'.

Is there a way so that I can copy and convert the JSON messages from the source topic to another topic in Avro format and point the HDFS sink connector to the new topic to read from? Can it be done using Kafka Streams?

My distributed Connect Config file contains --

```
...
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
...
```

My message for in the topic is as below --

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct",
           "fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"},
                     {"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},
                     {"type":"integer","optional":false,"field":"amount"}
                   ],
       "optional":false,
       "name":"myrec",
       "version":1
      },
 "payload":{"id":"A123","name":"Sample","amount":75}
}
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thanking in advance...

Comment: The config properties for the second connect daemon (to which the HDFS sink is registered) include -- key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter

Comment: You should not have to use a new topic. I suspect the error you are getting would help us see what's going on if you post it in full.